# Adding null value to NOT NULL table, org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException

Tags: java, hibernate

Using **hibernate** for data access.

I have a column in database:

```
varchar(40), default value is set to 0, NOT NULL
```

I have a case, that user sends null value, and getting error:

```
Error: org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: Cannot insert the value
    NULL into column 'foo', table 'MyTable'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
```

And the column in hibernate is defined like this:

```
@Column(name = "foo")
private String foo;
```

Where could the problem be? Must I define the default in hibernate annotations or smthing? How? Or any other suggetsions?

Comment: Why isn't the varchar default value ''?

Comment: If you want to put NULL to that column, why did you define the column as NOT NULL? was there any specific reason?

Comment: @shan I dont want to put null there, i want to put default value there, when user puts NULL

Comment: You need to look at the SQL generated though I suspect it is trying to put a NULL value in foo in which case the DB will not try to use the default value. Thus the failure, still don't know why default value of a varchar would be 0 though...

Comment: Default value for the column comes into effect than the column is **NOT assigned**, assigning NULL to the column is **NOT** the same  as the above. If you want to specifically enforce NULL -> default value conversion than teh best way would be to remove the assignment -> **NOT pass** any value for the column.   And, as mentioned by "ramsinb" 0 is **very unusual** default value for varchar column...

Comment: @ramsinb the value is not uncommon at all, I have values like `0` ´TEST` `12.2` there, so different stuff.

Comment: @GermannArlington It is passed anyways, because when I generate the object to send to database, it will use like `Object.setFoo(Class.getBar())` , so it will always get some value from `getBar()` or ´null`. So how can I handle the null in database. Isn't the "DEFAULT VALUE" in db used for this kind of stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What did you expect would happen when trying to insert `NULL` into a `NOT NULL` column? Either you want to enforce a `NOT NULL` constraint, and then you need to reject the user input, or you want to accept `NULL` values and need to specify that the column is nullable using, of course, `@Column(nullable = true)`.

---

Since you actually want a default value in the column when the user doesn't provide that field, and your code explicitely sets the field value even when it's null (or empty, which is the same for Oracle, for example), I suggest having a smarter setter on the field:

```
private String foo = "0";

public String getFoo() {
    return foo;
}

public void setFoo(String foo) {
    if (foo != null && !foo.isEmpty()) { // Or StringUtils.isNotBlank(foo)
        this.foo = foo;
    }
}
```

Comment: I dont want to put null there, i want to put default value in database, when user inserts NULL

Comment: Then assign a default value on the field: `private String foo = "default";`?

Comment: But my code overwrites it and sets it to null, can i somehow send null to not null column, and in database, when I see null, it will be default value that is set in my DB. Doesn't the "Default" work that way?

Comment: No, a `default` value on a table column doesn't work that way. The default value will be used if the column is _not_ specified in the SQL update/insert, but Hibernate will generate a request with all the mapped fields, so `foo` will always be there. You have to programatically set the value on your POJO, or you can modify your setter to ignore null/empty values so the default value stays there.

Answer (score 0):

Default value for `foo` would be null as it is class field.

As it's default value you are going to save is 0. 
Make `foo` primitive type if possible i.e. `int`. **If `foo` has to be String, then you may remove not-null constraint, because even if you don't assign value to `foo`, there is default value 0.**

Suggestion : Consider Automatic POJO classes generation using Hibernate-Tools. This will auto generate your POJO classes from existing database.

Comment: At the moment problem is that the database holds tons of null values in `foo` , but I want there to be `0` instead of `null`, and it doesnt do it by default.

Comment: @Jaanus : Your DB is going to be in inconsistent state. write update query to modify null values to 0. Something like : `update table set col=0 where col is null`

Comment: It doesnt matter, i truncated my table and just need all future records to hold value 0 instead of null. How to be able to do it? Vash solution is close to what I need.

Answer (score 0):

If you table do not allow null value you sould respect that and adopt your model.

As you are using @Column annotation you should first set the property nullable to false, to support the default value you should also use the column definition.

```
@Column(name = "foo", nullable = false, columnDefinition = “varchar(40) default 0″)
```

Comment: I added this, still getting same error. When I have varchar, can I have `default 0` or must do like `default '0'` ? Any suggetions?